# How to select cell in UITableView that in UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

I have added the `UITableView` as subview of `UIPickerViewRow` in this way:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
             numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return 1; 
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row 
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
           reusingView:(UIView *)view {

        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 216)];
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        return self.tableView;
}
```

But I can tap just to that cell, that situated in "Selection Indicator" area. For e.g. I have table from 1 to 5, and 3 situated in "Selection Indicator" area, I tap on it, it send message to didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but if I tap to 1-2 or 4-5 cell, it do nothing, then I scroll tableView to set some cell to "Selection Indicator" area, and it works fine.

How to change the size of tap area?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: what is the purpose of adding a UITableView inside a UIPickerView?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Just set the height of your row as height of your `UIPickerViewRow`.

```
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
          rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.pickerView.frame.size.height;
}
```